# Dynamically call a method within a class

Tags: php, laravel-5

You can call methods within the same class, so dynamic?

Within a class I want to have different methods with a pattern, so you can call them within a foreach loop

```
class MyClass 
{

    private $tables;

    function __construct(){
        $this->tables = array('a','b','n');
    }

    public function runMigrations() {
        foreach ($this->tables as $table) {
            // Excecute method migration_$table)
            call_user_func('migration_'.$table.'()');  // Try but not work  
            // call_user_func('this->migration_'.$table.'()');;  // Try but not work  
            // call_user_func('$this->migration_'.$table.'()');
        }
    }

    private function migration_a() {
        // Some code
    }

    ..

    private function migration_n() {
        // Some code
    }

}



[ErrorException]                                                                                                                
  call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'migration_a()' not found or invalid function name
```

Comment: `call_user_func([$this, 'migration_'.$table]);`

Comment: You can use the method @PeeHaa describes. Also note that you're not setting your `$tables` property in the class correctly. You must use `[` and `]` around an array, not `(` and `)`. Working example: https://3v4l.org/mm0Dq

Comment: Also note that there isn't even a reason to use `call_user_func` here at all. `$this->{'migration_'.$table}();` works as well.

Comment: A lot of thanks for all. I think the best way it's proposal by @PeeHaa. He believed it was necessary to call a callback.